# find duplicates in a column from a given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

example csv looks like this:

```
    name,id
    row1,1
    row2,2
    row3,3
    custom,test
    custom,test2
    row1,4
```

I defined an array of strings `nameRows = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']` for each row that I want to check a duplicate for. How can I check for a duplicate only for the rows in nameRows, under the 'name' column? and  ignore the other duplicate rows, like 'custom'. I just want a print statement that says print('{0} is a duplicate row in the name column'.format(row))

semi-related, i'm currently using this to very required rows exist under the name column and maybe I can use the same for loop to find the error...?

```
for row in nameRows:
    if row not in df['name'].values:
        print("Required {0} row 'name' not found in the csv file.".format(row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
nameRows = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']

for row in nameRows:
    if len(df[df['name'].str.contains(row , na=False)]) > 1:
       print(f'Row {row} is duplicate')
```

**Option 2**

```
nameRows = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']

for row in nameRows:
    if len(df[df['name'] == row]) > 1:
       print(f'Row {row} is duplicate')
```

Please use the **not** condition if you want the other way round.

Comment: I tried Option 2 (didn't try option 1) and it worked. Thank you! can you briefly explain to me how it works? (i'm still a newbie to all this)

Comment: The basic idea is to filter the rows that have the value mentioned in the nameRows list and then checking the length of the series. If the length is greater than one, then we can say there are duplicate rows. Hope this gives you the intuition behind the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isin` and `duplicated` to make a mask

```
msk=df.name.duplicated(keep='last') & df.name.isin(nameRows)
s=df[msk].name

print(s)

0    row1
Name: name, dtype: object
```

And to print it as you want:

```
for row in s:
    print(f'{row} is duplicated')

>>>row1 is duplicated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your df with

```
mask = df.name.isin(nameRows) # boolean mask
check = df.loc[mask, :]
nocheck = df.loc[~mask, :]
```

Then drop duplicates and concatenate back

```
df = pd.concat([
    check.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'], inplace=True),
    nocheck], ignore_index=True)
```

And to find which names are not in the dataframe

```
not_found = list(set(nameRows) - set(df.names))
```